# Strange diagonal viewBox SVG Behaviour

Tags: css, svg, position, viewbox, sizing

Trying to figure out how this svg viewBox thing works but sadly the code below is breaking all logic we know lol. Please someone explain if this is a bug or it's the correct svg behaviour. I can't see what I'm getting wrong...

```
<svg class="symbol"><symbol id="Atom" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 10 7"><path d="M3 6 4 7 6 7 4 4 5 3 8 7 10 7 5 0 0 7 2 7Z"></path></symbol></svg>
```

This my svg symbol here and I'm trying to stack more of them (both horizzontally and vertically)

```
//vertical stack ->viewBox = 0, 0, 10*1, 7*2
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 14">
      <use href="#Atom"/>
      <use href="#Atom" y="7"/> 
</svg>

//horizontal stack ->viewBox = 0, 0, 10*2, 7*1
<svg viewBox="0 0 20 7">
      <use href="#Atom"/>
      <use href="#Atom" x="10"/>    
</svg>

//"diagonal" stack ->viewBox = 0, 0, 10*2, 7*2
<svg viewBox="0 0 20 14">
      <use href="#Atom"/>
      <use href="#Atom" x="10"/>
      <use href="#Atom" y="7"/>
</svg>
```

First one is 2 symbols in vertical so I kept the same viewBox as the symbol but doubling the height from 7 to 14. Works perfectly.

Second one is 2 symbols in horizontal so I kept the same viewBox as the symbol but doubled the width from 10 to 20. Works as well.

Third one is 2 symbols in horizontal and 2 symbols in vertical making both viewBox's width and height twice as the original. This doesn't work.
[image: strange behaviour screenshot]

As you can see from the image the symbols get all messed up togheter (seems like I have a wrong viewBox)

[This](https://codepen.io/andreafuturi/pen/yLVqQxv) is kinda what I'm looking for (though as you can see I'm using overflow: visible and the symbols goes out of the viewbox)

[image: kinda expected result]

Can somebody explain me what I'm getting wrong here? Any help is really appreciated.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/andreafuturi/pen/JjbBeGa) for playing with this stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up replying to myself but I really want to thanks @ciekals11 for its input.

The solution to get the result I wanted was to specify width and height attributes in my symbol. This makes everything works perfectly. Not sure why it does need this, but anyway I'll share my symbol again so you can see the difference.

```
<svg class="symbol"><symbol width="10" height="7" id="Atom" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 10 7"><path d="M3 6 4 7 6 7 4 4 5 3 8 7 10 7 5 0 0 7 2 7Z"/></symbol></svg>
```

Comment: Simplest solution is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

your symbol want to take full width or height
when you stretch only one dimension of viewport then it fit nicely because it take full width or height and stops from stretching in other direction because it want to preserve aspect ratio.

But in this `svg` viewport is 2x bigger than symbol so it take it all

here is simple solution

```css
.svg {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 20 14">
    <use href="#Atom" x="0" y="0"  width="50%" />
    <use href="#Atom" x="0" y="7"  width="50%" />
    <use href="#Atom" x="10" y="0" width="50%" />
    <use href="#Atom" x="10" y="7" width="50%" />
</svg>
<svg class="symbol"><symbol id="Atom" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 10 7"><path d="M3 6 4 7 6 7 4 4 5 3 8 7 10 7 5 0 0 7 2 7Z"></path></symbol></svg>
```

---

UPDATE:

if you doesn't want to manually add `width` to `use` tag AND you are creating them programmatically then (I assumed that you use javascript but you could use same logic for other language) you just want to calc rows and columns in your viewport and calculate width and height of every `use`

here is an example

```js
const config = {
    svg: {
        width: 20,
        height: 14,
        rows: 2,
        cols: 2,
        symbol: '#Atom'
    }
}
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 '+config.svg.width+' '+config.svg.height);

for (let i = 0; i < config.svg.rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < config.svg.cols; j++) {
        const xPosition = (config.svg.width / config.svg.rows) * i;
        const yPosition = (config.svg.height / config.svg.cols) * j;

        const width = (100 / config.svg.rows);
        const height = (100 / config.svg.cols);

        const svgUse = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
        svgUse.setAttribute('href', config.svg.symbol);
        svgUse.setAttribute('x', xPosition);
        svgUse.setAttribute('y', yPosition);
        svgUse.setAttribute('width', width + '%');
        svgUse.setAttribute('height', height + '%');

        svg.append(svgUse);
    }
}

document.body.prepend(svg)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg class="symbol"><symbol id="Atom" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 10 7"><path d="M3 6 4 7 6 7 4 4 5 3 8 7 10 7 5 0 0 7 2 7Z"></path></symbol></svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks really much for your input. This is kinda what I want but since I'm doing this programatically I need a set of rule to calculate the symbol width percentage.
See https://codepen.io/andreafuturi/pen/yLVqQxv for an example of the problems that could occur.
Is there any way to do this without specifying the width attribute? Like changing my symbol preserveAspectRatio I'm not sure

Comment: `const width = (100 / config.svg.rows);
        const height = (100 / config.svg.cols);`

Comment: Yes. I am dividing 100 by number of rows to calculate percentage value of width of each element in row so that they will together take whole width of `svg` element. Same for height.

Comment: Thank you really much for your help, really appreciated.
Yes I'm using Javascript (ReactJS) for it. Unfortunately your solution works only when width & height are inline attributes. Since I have a lot of <use> generated in my frontend this would be fastly become garbage code. Unfortunately we can't set a global width and height for each <use> trough css. I came up with a more appropriate and global solution for the problem which I'm going to post as an answer.
Thanks again for your help

Comment: Updated with the answer!